# Unable to install angular 14 on M1 Mac

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular14upgrade

I am trying to install Angular 14 on M1 Mac but my angular cli is stuck on version 11. I have been trying to uninstall it using

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli` and ran `npm install -g @angular/cli@14` followed by `npm cache clean --force`

but still I get the following output when I run
`ng version`

[image]

Comment: You can restart the machine or terminal and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting terminal solved the problem. Thanks Vinay Somawat